# Simplify jQuery code showing/hiding form fields

Tags: jquery

I need to show some selects in a form or to hide them depending on the previous selected option. I think the code is very simple, here is the javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#A2').hide();
    $('#A3').hide();
    $('#A5').hide();
    $('#A6').hide();
    //A8, A9, A11...

    $('#A1').change(function(){
        if($(this).val() == "1"){
            $('#A2').show();
            $('#A2').focus();
        }
        else $('#A2').hide();
    });
    $('#A2').change(function(){
        if($(this).val() == "1"){
            $('#A3').show();
            $('#A3').focus();
        }
        else $('#A3').hide();
    });
    //the same with A4, A5, A7...
});
```

And here is a portion of the html:

```
<select name="A1" id="A1">
    <option selected="selected">¿Conoce?</option>
    <option value="1">Sí</option>
    <option value="0">No</option>
</select>
<select name="A2" id="A2">
    <option selected="selected">¿Ha usado?</option>
    <option value="1">Sí</option>
    <option value="0">No</option>
</select>
<select name="A3" id="A3">
    <option selected="selected">¿Nota?</option>
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="99">Ns/Nc</option>
</select>
//the same for A4-A6, A7-A9...
```

What I want is to create a function that will do this without tons of code... I have tested the next js but it doesn't work:

```
$.fn.validar1 = function(elem) {
    if(elem.val() == "1"){
        elem.next('select').show();
        elem.next('select').focus();
    }
    else elem.next('select').hide();
} 

validar1('#A1');
```

I know that my code is very bad... I'm starting with jQuery, please, have mercy :O)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is all you need, if the html and js you've shown is all you got:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('select').hide();

    $('select').change(function(){
        if($(this).val() == "1"){
            $(this).next().show().focus();
        }
        else $(this).next().hide();
    });
});
```

If this won't work, make a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: Not all the "selects" should be hidden. Please, note there are groups of three selects in my example; the first select in every group is showed always. Thank you very much!